# Reset password inside the app using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The question is about Firebase authentication :

Do you know how to reset password "inside" the app ? I know how to reset it through a link using this function :

firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email)

But I do not find a way to do it inside the app with flutter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snipped for updating user password.

```
user.updatePassword(newPassword).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

for more info, read https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users